# Covariance between two variables when one of the variables only has two possible values

Tags: statistics, regression, covariance, regression-analysis, linear-regression

I have a data set which consists of the results of a study to determine if texting while driving has a statistically significant effect on participant’s driving quality. Participant's were divided into two groups: one which were the control and completed the driving test without texting, the other that completed it while texting with one hand.

The data set consists of two variables: Condition (Control or Texting) and Score which is a real number in the range [0,7].

I do not have much of a statistics background, but am trying to determine the best way to graph the covariance between Condition and Score. Could I just plot all of the scores for the testing group in one vertical line, and the scores of the control group in another vertical line and then plot the regression between their two mean scores?

I'm sure that is not a good solution, so what would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

It's more informative to do a table. See slide 4 in [this](http://campus.greenmtn.edu/faculty/gregbrown/rec4031/Lecture--General%20Linear%20Model.pdf)

Comment: Can something like this be computed in R?